# Cannot set bind(to: UITableView) with RxSwift Variable asObservable()

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, rxdatasources

I'm trying to bind(to:) a collectionView, but the tableView doesn't work either. I have a viewModel where is my Variable<[]> and I want to subscribe when the value changes, with my tableView.

```
viewModel.theVariable
        .asObservable()
        .bind(to: tableView.rx.items(cellIdentifier: "Cell", cellType: UITableViewCell.self)){
            (row, item, cell) in
            cell.textLabel?.text = item
        }
        .addDisposableTo(disposeBag)
```

The XCode tells me `Type 'inout UITableView' does not conform to protocol 'ReactiveCompatible'` which should be since it's applicable to any UIView.

I've tried Observable with it's just() and that approach seemed to work correctly. The thing is that I need to have a Variable which I set a value in the viewModel and in the View i need to observe this change. Not sure if Observable serves this method.

The point is that this should work even with Variable? Is it a bug? Im using Swift 3.2

Comment: What's the type of your Variable ?

Comment: Custom model that I've created ...

Comment: Array Of Custom right ?

Comment: That is correct, I have a model that has Array, Int and Int in it. Thats what the Variable is observing

Comment: I'm Making a Playground example

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a working code example :

```
    var dataSource : PublishSubject<[String]> = PublishSubject()

    dataSource.asObservable().bind(to: self.mProductsCollectionView.rx.items) { (collectionView, row, element ) in
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "reuseIdentifier", for: IndexPath(row : row, section : 0))
        //customize cell
        return cell

    }.addDisposableTo(bag)

    publish.onNext(["blah", "blah", "blah"])
```

Comment: I will try this later today and if this is correct the bounty is yours :)

Comment: Any chance to try ?

Comment: Ok, so the problem seems to be that I'm using my own model which has an array in it. Seems like I need to use the array right away. So I've mapped the array as the input of the bind(to:) function and it seems to work. Maybe it will even work with the Variable. Thank you, the bounty is yours...

Answer (score 1):

Here is working code in Swift 3

```
 var countries = Variable([Country]())
 countries.asObservable()
  .bind(to: tblRx.rx.items(cellIdentifier: "RxCell", cellType: RxCell.self)) { (row, element, cell) in
            //customise cell here
        }
     .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```