# RxSwift in swift 4, binding data to a tableview

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift4, xcode9, rx-swift

I have a problem trying to follow this introduction to the MVVM pattern and RxSwift.

About half way down, he binds the data source (cars) to the tableView. This is the part I can't seem to get working in swift 4.

I'm using the following pods:

```
pod 'RxSwift', '4.0.0-beta.0'
pod 'RxCocoa', '4.0.0-beta.0'
```

This is the code I've tried with the error im getting (thought is was easier to see on a picture):
[image]

I have looked at all other questions mentioning a fix for this:
[RxSwift, RxCocoa and UITableview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46201795/rxswift-rxcocoa-and-uitableview) 
[Cannot set bind(to: UITableView) with RxSwift Variable asObservable()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46130494/cannot-set-bindto-uitableview-with-rxswift-variable-asobservable)

But can't seem to make it work with the swift 4 version.
Hope you guys can help me out :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The error message is misleading. The problem lies in the way you initialize your `cars` property. Your `cars` `Variable` wraps an **Optional type**. You cannot bind that to a table view.

Change the initialization to the following line and everything is fine:

```
var cars = Variable((UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).cars)
```

By the way, you do not have to wrap the `cars` array in a `Variable`, you can leave it as an Array:

```
let cars = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).cars
```

And then use Observable.of() to bind it to the table view:

```
Observable.of(cars).bind(to: tableView.rx.items(cellIdentifier: "CarCell", cellType: CarTableViewCell.self)) { (_, carViewModel: CarViewModel, cell) in
   cell.carViewModel = carViewModel
}.addDisposableTo(disposeBag)
```